# Advantage of using H in cron in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, cron

Is there a real big advantage of using `H` in cron in Jenkins?
Like:

```
H 21 * * 1-5
```

instead of

```
0 21 * * 1-5
```

I prefer the last step in my case because I really want to run the job on `06.00` etc. The warning in Jenkins is always showing:

```
Spread load evenly by using ‘H 21 * * 1-5’ rather than ‘0 21 * * 1-5’
```

Do I have to bee worried for this?

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not scheduling many jobs for the same time, you don't have to worry. Just the more you schedule for a certain time, the less likely it is that they can be executed in parallel (depending on the number of executors). If you just don't care about, when a job is executed, then give Jenkins the chance to distribute the load.